# “Thick layers” on Ender 3

Tags: creality-ender-3, print-quality, ultimaker-cura

Every time I print something I get these random bands on my prints that look like layers that are just too thick. I’ve tightened my X-axis belt to the best of my ability, and my Y-axis belt is tightened as well. Though I don’t think it’s that because it goes around the whole print.

I’m using Cura, .28 mm layer height, 20 % infill, all on my Ender 3 in PLA at 200 °C nozzle temp and 50-60 °C bed temp. I’ve attached some pictures of a calibration cube I printed, it is squished a bit because my Z-axis wasn’t calibrated properly, but I’ve since fixed that and the problem still occurs.

[image: Photo of a calibration cube with strange thick looking layers around the whole print]

Comment: What is the dimension of the cube in the Z axis?

Comment: This looks awfully close to [this recent question](https://3dprinting.stackexchange.com/questions/20318/how-to-i-eliminate-these-squished-layers-that-appear-on-my-prints)!

Comment: @0scar Thank you! Didn’t even see that.

Comment: @kosteklvp Supposed to be 20mm,  ended up 17.3 mm. I printed another after calibration and it ended up with the same dimensions and layers, so now I’m thinking I have a whole other problem on my plate (haha)

Comment: Yes, check and tighten everything around Z-axis. Check also, if your Z-axis isn't missing steps.

Comment: How do I check whether or not my Z axis is missing steps?

Comment: @0scar - If anyone (rightly) adds one more vote to close as a dupe, then the OP will not be able to accept their answer (I'm sure you can't accept an answer on a closed question). So... maybe wait until the OP accepts the answer and *then* close as dupe?

Comment: @Greenonline I'll keep the hammer in the toolbox 

Answer (score 3):

Problem solved everyone!! Turns out I was actually having two issues caused by the same thing. My inaccuracy in the z axis and those weird lines were both being caused by either my z axis stepped not receiving enough current or that the collar around the z axis lead screw wasn’t tight enough. I tried both of these solutions at the same time so I don’t know which it was.

[Link to a post with the same issue, with possibly the same solution. Thank you @0scar for showing me this!](https://3dprinting.stackexchange.com/questions/20318/how-to-i-eliminate-these-squished-layers-that-appear-on-my-prints)

Comment: Great, good to see that you got a solution. Please don't forget to mark your answer as the accepted answer. You may need to wait 48 hours (or so)